# No value provided for required options '--orm' Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been using Rails 2, recently switched to Rails 3. Got a big problem. Every time I try to rails generate a model or a scaffold, it keeps giving me the same error "No value provided for required options '--orm'". If I do rails generate controller newController, it works though. But just for model or scaffold, I can't get rid of that error message. I don't see many people having the same problem. So maybe there's a common Rails 3 setting that I miss here?

My machine is Debian Lenny, and rails version 3.0.7. Also I'm not using any db.

```
~/projects/rails/contacts$ rails generate model user
No value provided for required options '--orm'
```

Just for the record, I created another testing app with

```
rails new test_no_db --skip-active-record
```

Then

```
rails generate model User
```

Got exactly the same error message:

```
No value provided for required options '--orm'
```

Comment: Did you pass in any parameters to `rails new` when creating the app?

Comment: No. I didn't. I know you could pass a parameter to completely skip using any db. But the app might be using db in the future, just for now we don't need. So I created it in a usual way and disabled db access from config.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `rails generate model User`.

If that doesn't work either, it's likely you don't have the active_record railtie in your project (e.g. if you initiated the project with `rails new rails_demo --skip-active-record`). To fix that, do the opposite of this blog post: http://therailworld.com/posts/27-Disable-ActiveRecord-in-Rails-3

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the purpose of using '--skip-active-record' on app creation?

Comment: Yes, precisely. If by any chance the active record railtie wasn't included (e.g. when initiating the project), it won't be possible for ORM to work.

Comment: Yes, disabled active_record was my problem too.
@redspike I've disables my active record when the deployment to heroku had failed because I've started with only static pages and was going to implement resources later.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me:

```
rails generate model User --orm=mongo_mapper
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the --orm option to the rails generate or scaffold.

```
 rails generate model User name:string --orm=ORM_NAME
```

You can also set your orm in the application.rb file, incase you have not set it.

```
 config.orm             :active_record
```

I found it [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/216-generators-in-rails-3). It explains in detail

Comment: I tried to add the line config.orm :active_record in application.rb, but it didn't work. Thanks for the read. That was informative!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and added:

```
    rails generate scaffold Product title:string description:text image_uri:string price:decimal --orm mongo_mapper
```